# How to refactor model classes implementing similar methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, interface, refactoring

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.9 and Ruby 1.9.3. I have many model classes implementing similar methods as-like the following:

```
class ClassName_1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  def great_method
    self.method_1
  end

  def method_1 ... end
end

class ClassName_2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  def great_method
    result_1 = self.method_1
    result_2 = self.method_2

    result_1 && result_2
  end

  def method_1 ... end
  def method_2 ... end
end

...

class ClassName_N < ActiveRecord::Base
  def great_method
    result_1 = self.method_1
    result_2 = self.method_2
    ...
    result_N = self.method_N

    result_1 && result_2 && ... && result_N
  end

  def method_1 ... end
  def method_2 ... end
  ...
  def method_N ... end      
end
```

Those model classes behaves almost the same (*not* the same) since some of those has an interface with some less or more methods. All methods are differently named (for instance, `method_1` could be named `bar` and `method_2` could be named `foo`), all return `true` or `false`, are always the same in each class and there is no relation between them.

What is the proper way to refactor those classes?

---

*Note*: At this time I am thinking to refactor classes by including the following module in each one:

```
module MyModule
  def great_method
    result_1 = self.respond_to?(:method_1) ? self.method_1 : true
    result_2 = self.respond_to?(:method_2) ? self.method_2 : true
    ...
    result_N = self.respond_to?(:method_N) ? self.method_N : true

    result_1 && result_2 && ... && result_N
  end
end
```

But I don't know if it is the proper way to accomplish what I am looking for. Furthermore, I am not sure of related advantages and disadvantages...

Comment: Have you thought about using inheritance instead? Have one main model say `MainModel < ActiveRecord::Base` and have your subsequent models do `ClassName_1 < MainModel`, and so on...

There's a thing called [Single Table Inheritance](http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html), you might want to look at it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the best abstraction likely depends on the specific domain model, so it would help to have more details about what the domain model is. For example, is `method_1` always the same in each class? What is the relationship between `method_1` and `method_2`?

Comment: @Vincent Paca - I think inheritance is not a good thing...

Comment: @Ben Taitelbaum - (1) `method_1`, `method_2` and so on are always the same in each class; (2) There is no relation between `method_1` and `method_2`. *BTW*: I updated the question...

Comment: @user12882 if you have decide to rule out using inheritance maybe you should mention that in the question? In particular it might be useful to mention _why_ you have ruled it out. Otherwise you're Seem to be rejecting suggestions arbitrarily which does not seem like a fun conversation to jump into.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're on the right track. If the method_n methods are unique to your classes then just build the module that you already have into a superclass that each ClassNameN inherits from:

```
class SuperClassName < ActiveRecord::Base
  def great_method
    #... what you have in your module
  end
end

class ClassNameN < SuperClassName
  def method_1 ... end
  def method_2 ... end
end
```

There may be additional ways for you to factor out code depending on what goes on in your method_n methods, but it's impossible to say without more detail.

Comment: I think (not only me...) that inheritance has many drawbacks compared to the `include MyModule` approach. It is for what that I am trying to refactoring the code by using the latter approach.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a metaprogramming solution to clean this up somewhat.

```
module BetterCode
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def boolean_method(name, *components)
      define_method name do
        components.all? { |c| send c }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And in your models:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include BetterCode

  boolean_method :great_method, :foo, :bar, :baz, :quux
end
```

Instances of `MyModel` will then respond to `great_method` with a boolean value indicating whether or not `foo`, `bar`, `baz` and `quux` are all true.

Comment: Or use `ActiveSupport::Concern` just for a little more clarity.

Comment: Edited my answer to use `ActiveSupport::Concern`.

Answer (score 0):

You can abstract out the `great_method` with something like this:

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module Greatest
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    attr_accessor :num_great_methods

    def has_great_methods(n)
      @num_great_methods = n
    end
  end

  def great_method
    (1..self.class.num_great_methods).each do |n|
      return false unless self.__send__("method_#{n}")
    end
    true
  end
end

class ClassName_3
  include Greatest

  has_great_method 3

  # stub out the "method_*" methods
  (1..3).each do |n|
    define_method "method_#{n}" do
      puts "method_#{n}"
      true
    end
  end
end

puts ClassName_1.new.greatest
```

Comment: Sorry, but methods are *differently* named (for instance, `method_1` could be named `bar` and `method_2` could be named `foo`).

Comment: just update `has_great_method` to take a `*args` array so you can call it with something like `has_great_methods :foo, :bar`, although there's definitely a diminishing return on abstracting when it doesn't seem like there's much to abstract.